# How do you find out the Oracle database's URL?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

How can I find out the URL and port for an Oracle database?

Example:

> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:dbName","userName", "password");

Is there an SQL command or log/configuration file I can look at?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With oracle, there is a `tnsnames.ora` file which defines database addresses. This file is normally found in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` and is used by oracle clients like sqlplus or Toad. Here is a sample tns entry:

```
ORA11 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
    )
  )
```

From this entry you can work out that your jdbc connection string would be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:ORA11
```

Comment: Note that "ORA11" occurs twice in the example: once as the name of the entry (the very beginning of the example) and once as the value of SERVICE_NAME. Oracle does not require these to be the same, and it's the SERVICE_NAME value that belongs in your connection string.

Answer (score 7):

By reading the documentation which came along with the JDBC driver in question.

In case of the Oracle JDBC thin driver, you can find it [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/java.920/a96654/basic.htm#1006213).

> #### Specifying a Database URL, User Name, and Password
>
> The following signature takes the URL, user name, and password as separate parameters:
>
> ```
> getConnection(String URL, String user, String password);
> ```
>
> Where the URL is of the form:
>
> ```
> jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>
> ```
>
> The following example connects user scott with password tiger to a database with INSTANCE_NAME orcl through port 1521 of host myhost, using the Thin driver.
>
> ```
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
>               ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");
> ```
>
> If you want to use the default connection for an OCI driver, specify either:
>
> ```
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection 
>               ("jdbc:oracle:oci:scott/tiger@");
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection 
>               ("jdbc:oracle:oci:@", "scott", "tiger");
> ```
>
> For all JDBC drivers, you can also specify the database with a Oracle Net keyword-value pair. The Oracle Net keyword-value pair substitutes for the TNSNAMES entry. The following example uses the same parameters as the preceding example, but in the keyword-value format:
>
> ```
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
>               (jdbc:oracle:oci:@MyHostString","scott","tiger");
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
>     ("jdbc:oracle:oci:@(description=(address=(host= myhost)
>     (protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=orcl)))",
>     "scott", "tiger");
> ```

Comment: OP wants to know where the values `myhost`, `1521` and `orcl` come from.

Comment: @dogbane: As stated in the documentation, `myhost` is the DB host (hostname of machine where DB server runs, an IP address is also applicable and faster, if it's the same machine as where Java code runs, then use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`), `1521` is the DB port (TCP/IP port where DB is listening on, if you didn't change anything during DB setup, it defaults to 1521), `orcl` is the databasename (as you used in `CREATE DATABASE`).